# Any one can suggest: want to integrate stripe payment in laravel 5.2 project.

Tags: laravel-5

I want to integrate stripe payment gateway in my laravel 5.2 project. I gone through with four-five blog and also laravel docs, but not succeed. suggest me, good links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing)

[Stripe official doucmentation](https://stripe.com/docs)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGtyLk2s5-k&list=PLUpnKy5Si8zCpDcvIzB-hUZaBdiK6aDgZ&nohtml5=False)

Comment: galsyan: Thank you so much